# Change color according to conditions for seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have generated an heatmap with seaborn with the following code:

```
sns.heatmap(df.sort_index(axis=1), cmap="YlOrRd_r", center=0.8, square=True, annot=annot_df.sort_index(axis=1), annot_kws={"size":22, "va": "center_baseline", "color":"white"}, fmt="", xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, linewidth=1, linecolor="grey", vmax=1, vmin=0.5)
```

Now I would like to color differently, for example in blue, all the cells with a value > 0.9, while the other ones should remain with the red-to-yellow palette. Is there an easy way to implement this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could draw the heatmap a second time with a blue colormap, leaving out the annotations and setting a mask to only draw the value larger than 0.9 (the mask hides the unwanted cells).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

labels = list('abcdef')
N = len(labels)
heatm = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1, (N, N))
ax = sns.heatmap(heatm, cmap="YlOrRd_r", center=0.8, square=True, annot=True,
                 annot_kws={"size": 12, "va": "center_baseline", "color": "white"}, fmt=".2f", 
                 xticklabels=labels, yticklabels=labels, linewidth=1, linecolor="grey", vmin=0.5, vmax=1, cbar=False)
ax = sns.heatmap(heatm, mask=heatm < 0.9, cmap='Blues', square=True, annot=False, vmin=0, vmax=1, cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]